# How to log on JBoss console

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

I'm experimenting with Netbeans and JBoss and I'd like to print stuff on JBoss console from my code. Can I use log4j for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Edit $JBOSS_HOME/server/[config]/conf/jboss-log4j.xml to add a category if you want to display lower than INFO (the default level).

[config] --> one of default, minimal, web, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`import org.jboss.logging.Logger;`

```
Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()).info("put your message here");
```

In jboss7 , and mode StandAlone, your logs will be here:
`\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log`